# Phone call intent

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with this phonecall intent.

my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+32123456789"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

with permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

So, when i hit the button that triggers the event, my phone is ready to make to call.
Now when i hit the back button, he goes back to my app AND he makes a phone call in the background.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Back button didn't end the call normally in most devices.

Comment: But it is just by pressed the back button that starts the phone call.

Comment: Are you trying to cancel the Phone-Call by back button in PhoneApp.

Comment: No, by the physical button on my phone (htc one v)

Comment: My advice is to use Intent.ACTION_DIAL to give user an opportunity to make sure he want's to make a call. It is rather common practice

Comment: The behavior of back button is defined by the foreground application which is Phone application in this case. There's no way you'd be able to control the behavior of back button in some other app. You should rather use Intent.ACTION_DIAL to give an option to the use to call or cancel, as mentioned by @Scramysun above.

Comment: Intent.ACTION_DIAL works perfectly! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use permission in `manifest.xml` file as some intents need permission to call.
As you can see on this [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-make-phone-call-your-application), first file is manifest.xml

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

Edit: Sorry, I didn't analyzed the question well..  It's the same..

Comment: This appears to be the same code that has been posted in the request.

Comment: I noticed that after, but I can't delete the post..  :S